# Identify records where the balance equal zero

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like the example below, with date, num, debit, credit and balance (debit value + 0 - credit value), so I'd like to select the records with the same number and the balance sum was equal 0 then identify these records.

I'm trying to create a function, but I did only where there are two equal records. In this example, it was the num 219900. In the others cases, I couldn't.

I'd like to do in the others records, that's between **.

```
date        num     debit   credit      balance   zero_balance
11/11/2016  219900          470,00      -470,00     Y
11/11/2016  219900  470,00              470,00      Y

01/11/2016  218295  163,00              163,00    
30/11/2016  218295  162,00              162,00      **Y**
30/11/2016  218295  162,00              162,00      **Y**
30/11/2016  218295          162,00      -162,00     **Y**
30/11/2016  218295          162,00      -162,00     **Y**
30/11/2016  218295  162,00              162,00  

25/10/2016  218102  935,46              935,46      **Y**
25/10/2016  218102          935,46      -935,46     **Y**
25/10/2016  218102  935,46              935,46

20/10/2016  217638  1.896,65            1.896,65    **Y**   
20/10/2016  217638          1.896,65    -1.896,65   **Y**   
20/10/2016  217638  1.896,65            1.896,65    **Y**   
20/10/2016  217638          1.896,65    -1.896,65   **Y**   
20/10/2016  217638  1.696,65            1.696,65
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: So, are you interested only in pairs (where balances equal to zero while one row can only be in one pair)?

Comment: @pozs Yes, when a record there is your opposite, one would nullify the other, because I need to export this and show only the credits or debits opened.

Comment: Do you have a primary key in this table? (it is usually the best to all table have them and in your case it is a requirement: without it you cannot make sure that a record will only be used in one pair)

Comment: Also, with primary keys in mind, what rows should be marked with `zero_balance` when there are multiple candidates? (f.ex. `num = 218295` has 2x `credit = 162.00` and 3x `debit = 162.00` so one debit row will have `false` while others `true`, but which one should be which one)?

Comment: @pozs I don't have a primary key, because I'm working with a auxiliary table, but I can create this.
And, yes I need that mark the multiples and the row which can be marked false, it can be the row with the last date or the last primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll call your table `t` (use your own name in your queries). Also, I won't use the `balance` field at all; it seems redundant (but the answer is usable with that column too).

If you have a primary key, you just have to give each `num`'s credits and debits an index (`cd_idx` below). You can use that index to search for pairs.

```
with d as (
  select t r, row_number() over (partition by num, credit, debit order by date, id) cd_idx
  from t
)
select    (d1.r).*, (d2.r).id is not null zero_balance
from      d d1
left join d d2 on (d1.r).id <> (d2.r).id
and       (d1.r).num = (d2.r).num
and       d1.cd_idx = d2.cd_idx
and       ((d1.r).credit = (d2.r).debit or (d1.r).debit = (d2.r).credit)
order by  (d1.r).id
```

Note, that `cd_idx` is generated for the same `num, credit, debit` tuples in ascending order by `date, id`. Also note, that I put the entire rows into the `r` column, but you don't have to if you want to select just specific columns (this way I could easily select all *attributes* of that row with `(d1.r).*`).

If you don't have a primary key, you could use `row_number()` to temporarily generate one, but that way you are not guaranteed to get the same result for multiple execution.

```
with t as (select *, row_number() over () id from t),
d as (
  select t r, row_number() over (partition by num, credit, debit order by date, id) cd_idx
  from t
)
select    (d1.r).*, (d2.r).id is not null zero_balance
from      d d1
left join d d2 on (d1.r).id <> (d2.r).id
and       (d1.r).num = (d2.r).num
and       d1.cd_idx = d2.cd_idx
and       ((d1.r).credit = (d2.r).debit or (d1.r).debit = (d2.r).credit)
order by  (d1.r).id
```

[Rextester](http://rextester.com/RTDRZG80126)

Comment: I think it works like I want. But I forgot just one situation: there are case that there is one record for credit and two or more for debit, or vice versa, but the balance sum is equal zero. I will use this and I will try to adjust the other way. Thanks!

Comment: @thiagofred that case unfortunately is really not easy. If there are multiple valid pairings, you will need to do something like [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking), because there may be a valid candidate of `C1 = D1 + D2` and `C2 = D3 + D4 + D5`, but the "normal" search may find the `C1 = D6 + D2 + D5` first and then it cannot find any more because `C2 ≠ D1 + D3 + D4`

Comment: I did the query and saved them in another table. After that I did a function that select the rows that have zero balance = false and did a function to compare the debit sum with the credit sum, when this result is equal, I set the zero balance with true.
I believe it's not most correct or efficient way to do this, but at the moment it's is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html
I think it should help you.

```
select
    date
    ,num
    ,debit
    ,credit
    ,sum(debit) over (partition by num) as sum_deb
    ,sum(credit) over (partition by num) as sum_cred
    ,case when
         sum(debit) over (partition by num) = sum(credit) over (partition by num)
         then 'Y' else 'N' end as zero_balance
from test_debt
```

Comment: this is a good help, but it's not yet what I need. I don't explain correctly, but I need that when one record was the opposite value, both should be identify. Because there're 7 records with the same num but at least one there isn't your opposite and just this wouldn't be identified.